# Why does isNaN for form input true for a string only if I enter quotes around it?

Tags: javascript, validation

I've seen this in JavaScript in numerous examples but I can't get this to work for me. I must be overlooking something, so I would appreciate a kind soul helping me out here because I am new to JavaScript:

```
 spend=eval(form.spend.value);
 if(isNaN(form.spend.value)) {
     alert('I am not a number');
 }
```

The above form input is gathered from:

```
<input type=text name=spend value="" size=6 STYLE="background-color: #EDEDE8;">
```

If I enter in abc as input, the alert I am not a number doesn't display. If I enter "abc" with quotes around is, it does display the alert.

I am checking input from the form where the user should only be allowed to enter numbers. Only numbers should be accepted. Thank you!

Edit: spend is US dollar amount. So it needs to be able to accept amounts such as 123.45.
Edit2: Sorry, num is indeed form.spend.value.

Comment: You should be using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), not `eval`.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Or (usually more appropriate) `Number(form.spend.value)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, James. Sorry, I should mention the numbers are dollar amounts (US) such as 123.45. Wouldn't parseInt strip out the two decimal places then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check this code, its working.
js:

```
function abc(){
var aa = document.getElementById('myid').value;
if(isNaN(aa)) {
 alert('I am not a number');
}
}
```

form :

```
<input type=text name=spend value="" id="myid" size=6 STYLE="background-color: #EDEDE8;">
    <input type="button" onClick="abc();">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So it is better to use id= on the input line and use cument.getElementById than simply relying on the name=spend? Does the document.getElementById treat the form input data differently? Thanks!

Comment: @Edward_178118 — The significant difference here is that the `eval` line has been discarded (as explained in my and Alvin's answers)

Comment: you can use id when you want to get data from single input field, because id is unique, you can not give same id to diff input fields. and name is not unique property, you can give same name to more then one input field. generally name is use for check box or radio button, etc.

Comment: @Edward_178118 you can still use the `name` attribute with `document.getElementsByName` as long as you can identify, like in my answer

Comment: @Alvin Wong you are right but id is unique and name is not unique so its better to use id in place of name..

Answer (score 1):

Because this is not a proper way to process a number.

```
spend=eval(form.spend.value); // Problem is on this line
if(isNaN(form.spend.value)) {
    alert('I am not a number');
}
```

If someone enters something in `form.spend.value` for example like `alert("foolish")` you will surprisingly see it being executed, like `eval("alert(\"foolish\")")`

If it is something like `this_is_an_undefined_variable_name` it throws an error and terminates the script, that's why you won't see the alert.

If it is something like `"hihi"`, as this is a valid JavaScript **string** no error was thrown and you will see the alert.

Just like James McLaughlin have pointed out, you should use the proper functions to process a number.

---

By the way it should be better to write your HTML correctly (quote the attributes):

```
<input type="text" name="spend" id="spend" value="" size="6" STYLE="background-color: #EDEDE8;">
```

And use a better way to retrieve the form (use `document.getElementsByName` is also fine):

```
spend=parseFloat(document.getElementById("spend").value);
// OR
spend=parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("spend")[0].value);

if(isNaN(spend)) {
    alert('I am not a number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I enter in abc as input, the alert I am not a number doesn't display. If I enter "abc" with quotes around is, it does display the alert.

That is because the script errors and dies before reaching the alert.

```
> var form = { spend: { value: 'abc' } };
>  spend=eval(form.spend.value);
ReferenceError: abc is not defined
```

If the value had quotes around it (i.e. `'"abc"'`), then it would be evaluated as a string literal instead of a variable.

You shouldn't be putting `eval` anywhere near user input. Just remove that line.

Comment: num was my mistake, I corrected it above. It should be form.spend.value in place of num.

Comment: @Edward_178118 — Same problem, it just hits on the eval line.